# Solve 1 equation and 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know that I should have infinite solutions when this is the case, but I don't know how to derive the solution without just using some logic and it seems like there should be a way to solve it mathematically (maybe some simple linear algebra?)

$$
s^2 + 2s = b(s^2+3s+2) + a_1(s+2) + a_2
$$
Clearly the only term with an $s^2$ on it it is $b$ and since we only want one $s^2$ we see that $b=1$. Now we need to cancel out one of the $3s$ we got because we only want $2s$ so $a_1$ must be $-1$. Conveniently this canceled out the $2$ for us so $a_2 = 0$.

While this makes sense, I want to use math to solve it.

---

Alright although the question is already solved I'll provide a little bit more background for the question if future people are curious.

I'm given

$$
G(s) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{s+1} \\ \frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)}\end{bmatrix}
$$

$G(s) = C(sI-A)^{-1}B + D$ but in the problme I'm given that $D$ is a vector of zeros, and C is the identity matrix.

My goal was to find A and B that satisfied.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot x_1 \\
\dot x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 \\
a_3 & a_4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Given $G(s)$.

Comment: I would say what you're describing *is* using math.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a polynomial with variable $s$?  In other words is this supposed to be true for all $s$?  Other wise to say "you want only one $s^2$ so $b=1$" isn't valid because if $s$ is just a number then $bs^2$ can be added to $2s$ or so $a_2$ with no issue.

Comment: It's only if $s$ is the variable of polynomial that considering that the $s^2$ terms must be keep distinct from the $s$ terms kept distinct from the "constant" terms.  But if this is a polynomial then you don't have just *one* equation.  You have $3$-- one for the $s^2$ terms, one for the $s$ terms and one of the "constant" terms.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, I want it to be true for all s. I didn't think about it like that but that helps. It's deriving a the solution for a state space model where I know the transfer function as well as the values of the "hidden states" but I want to find the $A$ matrix and input vector. I'll edit the question to give more context.

Comment: Two things you can do.  1) Just let $s= 0$ and $s=1$ or $s=-1$ or $s=$ anything that makes it easy.  And you will get relations between the terms.  Or 2) you can treat these as polynomials.  They will be equal if and only if the coefficients are equal.  (And three coefficients for three powers of $s$ [$s^0,s^1,s^2$] will mean *three* equations and three unknowns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear from the question what is known and what is unknown, but in this answer I *presume* you want to find $b, a_1, a_2$ such that:

$$s^2 + 2s = b(s^2+3s+2) + a_1(s+2) + a_2$$

*as a polynomial* in $s$, i.e. that all the coefficients (multiplying the powers of $s$) in the LHS are the same as all the coefficients in the RHS.

For that, re-origanise RHS as a polynomial in $s$:

$$s^2 + 2s +0= \underbrace{b}_1 s^2+\underbrace{(3b+ a_1)}_2 s +\underbrace{(2b+2a_1+ a_2)}_0$$

which yields a system of *three* equations in three unknowns:

$$\begin{array}{rrrcl}b&&&=&1\\3b&+a_1&&=&2\\2b&+2a_1&+a_2&=&0\end{array}$$

which has a unique solution: $b=1, a_1=-1, a_2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely.
All you need to do is expand the RHS and collect like terms: $$b(s^2+3s+2)+a_1(s+2)+a_2=(b)s^2+(3b+a_1)s+(2b+2a_1+a_2)$$ and match co-efficients with the LHS, i.e.: $$\begin{cases} b=1 \\ 3b+a_1=2 \\ 2b+2a_1+a_2=0\end{cases}$$
Which is easily solved for $(b, a_1,a_2)=(1,-1,0)$

Answer (score 1):

Is the $s$ an unknown variable to solve?

If so there really isn't much to say you have $1$ equation and $4$ unknowns and although you can solve for $s$ with that quadratic equation and have the solution in terms of $a_1, a_2, b$ so long as they are so that the radicand is not negative, there isn't much point as $a_1, a_2, b$ are for all practical purposes unlimited.

(That is to say $s^2(1-b) + (2-3b -a_1)s -a_2 = 0$ so

$s = \frac {3b +a_1-2 \pm \sqrt{(2-3b-a_1)^2 + 4a_2(1-b)}}{2-2b}$

so long as $(2-3b-a_1)^2 + 4a_2(1-b) \ge 0$ and $b\ne 1$ we can have $a_1, a_2, b$ be anything at all)

.....

Or is this supposed to be true for all $s$ no matter what $s$ is?

Then you don't have $1$ equation and $3$ unknowns; you have *infinite* equations and three unknowns.

So $s=0$ and $a_2 = 0$.

Let $s = 1$ and you have $(1-b) + (2-3b - a_1) = -4b-a_1 + 3 = 0$ so $a_1 = 3-4b$.

Let $s = -1$ and you have $(1-b)-(2-3b -a_1) = 2b +a_1 -1 = 0$ so $a_1 = 1-2b$

So $3-4b = 1-2b$ so $2b = 2$ so $b =1$ and $a_1=3-4 =1-2 = -1$.

....

Saying it true for all $s$ is equivalent so say we have an equation between polynomials.

$s^2 + 2s = b(s^2+3s+2) + a_1(s+2) + a_2$

On the LHS we have the polynomial $P(s) = s^2 + 2s$ and on the RHS we have the polynomial $R(x) = bs^2 + (3b + a_1) s + (2a_1 + 2b + a_2)$

Two say two *polynomials* are equal is to say 1) the always have the same value for all $s$ *OR* it is to say 2) the coefficients are equal.

ANd if the coefficients are equal then ... well, then its *three* equations (one for each coefficient) and $3$ unknowns.

The three equations are

1)$1=b$
2)$2=3b+a_1$
3)$0 = 2a_1 + 2b+a_2$

So $b= 1$ and $2=3+a_1$ so $a_1 = -1$ and $2(-1)+2 + a_2 = 0$ so $a_2 = 0$.